# 24 hours schedule- Time Diff

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have to build a 24 hours schedule for all personnel distributed around the globe.

So, for example, somebody can start working at 10:00 and end working at 19:00, so it is very simple to get the time difference since the end time and start time are on the same day. But, if I have somebody who starts working at 19:00 and ends at 04:00 on next day, I will get a negative time difference.

I need to do this continuously,  not date specific but it has to repeat weekly. Can you please give me an idea what is the best way to do this?

```
+------------------+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
| name             | day | start_time | end_time | total     |
+------------------+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
| Test01           | fri | 06:00:00   | 15:00:00 | 09:00:00  |
| Test             | fri | 07:00:00   | 16:00:00 | 09:00:00  |
| Test02           | fri | 08:00:00   | 14:30:00 | 06:30:00  |
| Pablo Quesada    | fri | 22:00:00   | 01:30:00 | -20:30:00 |
+------------------+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `case` statement does what you need:

```
select (case when start_time < end_time
             then timediff(end_time, start_time)
             else timediff(addtime(end_time, '24:00:00', start_time))
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple if-statement:

```
SELECT IF( end_time > start_time,
           end_time - start_time,
           end_time + 240000 - start_time ) as total
FROM timetable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP's time function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) for this task. `time()` returns the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.

Store start time as (example)

```
$startTime = time() + (2 * 3 * 20 * 43); // now + 2days, 3hrs, 20mins; 43secs
```

and their end time to some time after that. If you subtract their start time from their end time the result will always be a positive number of seconds that they spent working. You also won't need the day column since the $time function returns the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, so you have the date there as well, for free.

In your UI, you can then format the resulting number of seconds to a usable time and date using [PHP's date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback guys. With your help, I did it as follows:

select IF( end_time > start_time, TIMEDIFF (end_time,start_time), TIMEDIFF (addtime(end_time,'24:00:00') ,start_time)) as Total_Hours 
from timetable;